# Why is my CSS Media Query being ignored or overridden? (tumblr)

Tags: image, responsive-design, media-queries

This is my CSS:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 640px){
.double{width:260px;}
.double img{width:100%;height:auto;}
.title {font-size:50px;}
}
```

No matter how much I edit the `@media screen and (max-width: 640px)` property, nothing works. I have tried adding `!important` as well, but it doesn't work.

It seems like my `@media` property is being ignored/overridden because when I resize the browser and inspect the element (on FireFox), the CSS used is still `.double img{width:560px;}` when it should be `.double img {width:100%;height:auto;}`

Any help would be really appreciated! :)

[Here's my Tumblr.](http://vyww.tumblr.com/)
And if it helps, my JSFiddle is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/vyww/7yVY6/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's simply caused by a syntax error in the `.capz` class, juste before your media query :

```
.capz {
     opacity:0;
    filter:alpha(opacity = 0);
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    position: absolute;
    background: rgba(255,255,255; //missing closing parenthesis
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    bottom:3px;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 640px){
    .double{width:260px;!important}
    .double img{width:100%!important;height:auto !important;}
    img {max-width: 100% !important;height: auto !important;}
}
```

(Note : you don't need `!important` tag anymore in this case)

[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zessx/7yVY6/3/)

Comment: I have been trying to figure out what's wrong for days now, can't believe I missed this out! I really feel like an idiot now haha. Thank you!! :)

Comment: @user2446412 Glad to have helped, please set this question as answered if you consider it as.